# Only allow users in my htpasswd list to access a file, but also allow wordpress to access the file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an XML file that I want to be only accessed by users via my wordpress deployment - but not if they try and access the file directly.

Is that possible?

I tried the following but it doesn't appear to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://my-domain.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(xml)$ - [NC,L,F]
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance, love this community.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

Put the sensitive config file outside of the web root. The httpd follows the local file system hierarchies and privileges, not its own (virtual) virtual structure.

If your host does not allow this, you can restrict any HTTP requests to the files using .htaccess. Put the config file in a separate directory with a .htaccess file that blocks everybody (or a list of IPs, etc).

```
<Files important.xml>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

Since the web server still can read and execute the file PHP can access and process it too.

Comment: Your first method: how do I access a file outside of htdocs via http though? (I need wordpress to access that)

Comment: Your second method (htaccess): I still need to be able to access via http, just from the local server itself. Basically, I need to stop people accessing the file directly, unless the request is coming the request is coming from the server itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the file directly"? To request it like http://localhost/my/config.xml via browser?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. It's okay, I've sorted this now by using the htaccess method described in the answer, and allowing 127.0.0.1 - thanks loads for your help.

Comment: @MattDonaldson Great. If the answer was helpful to you please [upvote/accept](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).